# laravel 5.4 convert collection of eloquent object to integer

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

When i try to compare collection of object with an integer..here

```
@if($in_closet == $product->id )
                <li><a id="add_closet" href="{{ route('user.addtocloset', ['id' => $product->id]) }}"><i class="fa fa-archive" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add to closet</a></li>
                @else
                <li><a id="my_closet" href="{{ route('closet') }}"><i class="fa fa-archive" aria-hidden="true"></i> My Closet</a></li>
                @endif
```

In `$in_closet` variable i am having collection of object like this [50,52,53,54] when i try to compare with `$product->id` having value as integer it show me this error

> Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted
>   to int

This is in my controller variable

```
   $in_closet = ProductCloset::where('closet_id',$user->id)->pluck('product_id');
```

I now find the problem but how my question is how to resolve it what i exactly need is if the product id equals to  any product id in that collection object show one div else show another div..

I want to know how to compare collection object to integer or how did i achieve this ..please any one help to find solution to this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare a `Collection` object with an Integer. If you want to know whether `$product->id` is in `$in_closet`, you should use the `contains()` method that is available to you. See more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-contains)

So, as `$in_closet` is a collection, you can check if it contains a specific element as follows:

```
if($in_closet->contains($product->id))
{
    // it contains the element
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mozammil i get the exact answer thank you so much

Comment: Great. Can you accept this answer if it helped you? @Karthiga